# how we can add element at the starting of array in every operation and compute sum of any given range.?

Tags: tree, adhoc, segment

You are initially given an array of `N` integers `( 1<=N<=105 )`. Given this array, you have to perform 2 kinds of operations :

```
(i) Operation 1 : Op1( l, r )
```

You are given 2 integers `l` and `r`. `( 1 <= l <= r <= current size of the array )`. You need to return the sum of all the elements with indices between `l` and `r` ( both inclusive ). That is, if the elements currently in the array are a1, a2, a3.... an, you need to return the following `sum : al + al+1 + al+2 ... + ar`.

```
(ii) Operation 2 : Op2( x )
```

You are given a single integer x `( |x| <= 109 )`. Add this element to the beginning of the array. After this operation, `x` will now become `a1`, the `old a1` will now become `a2`, and so on. The size of the array will increase by `1`.

I made segment tree with the initial given array and could compute range sum....but how i could add one element in segment tree and modify it accordingly?

Answer (score 0):

For this type of problem you can use Data Structure know as TREAP (Randomized Binary Search Tree).
For more info on treap follow this link -- cs.cornell.edu/Courses/cs312/2003sp/lectures/lec26.html

Answer (score -1):

Try this offline algorithm:-

First read in the array a.

Then read in all the queries and store them and also count the no of type 2 queries, let it be K.

Now create a new array b of length K+length of(a).

Now starting at index 1 in b and traversing your queries backwards, for every type 2 query add its element to array b.

Now build a Segment tree or Binary Indexed tree on array b.

Use a variable c to count the no of type 2 queries encountered till now and initialize it to 0.

Then traverse your list of queries and for each query of type 2 just increment c by 1.

For query of type 1 having range l...r in array a, its range in array b will correspond to (l+k-c)...(r+k-c).

So use the Segment tree or Binary indexed tree built above to answer this query on the transformed range.
I hope that it was helpful.